# Is there any use in dupping a Ruby class? (I'm doing crude mocking.)

Tags: ruby, class, module, mocking

I have this situation, in which I define an instance method which returns a "safe to tamper" testing dummy of the class itself.

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'shoulda'

module TestExtension
  def provides_tested_class_dummy
    self.class_exec do
      def tested_class_dummy
        txt = "class #{@tested_class.name}Dummy < #{@tested_class.name}; end"
        sub = self.singleton_class.class_eval txt
        duplicated = sub.dup
        duplicated.class_exec do
          # do evil things to the dummy,
          # such as redefining constants and stubbing methods
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Test::Unit::TestCase.extend TestExtensions
```

Pleas don't laugh yet. I'm doing this because it works for what I need to do, namely to test classes and do bad things to their dummies without touching the the tested classes in any way.

```
class SomeClass
  # define some constants
  # define some methods
end
```

Then, testing it:

```
class SomeClassTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  @tested_class = ::SomeClass
  provides_tested_class_dummy()

  should "somehow comply" do
    dummy = tested_class_dummy()
    assert_kind_of Module, dummy
    # other assertions about the dummy's behavior
  end
end
```

Now you can start laughing.

My main question is, in the line "duplicated = sub.dup", where I duplicate the subclassed tested class, does that line make any sense? From me, it's voodoo, I'm doing it just to minimize any negative effects of the tampering done to the dummy on the tested class itself. Am I gaining anything by #dup-ping a class?

Side question: If I'm doing something blatantly laughable, please tell me. I simplified this code and I am not really sure how it would work (the more complicated original does work as intended for me), but I hope you can at least get the idea. Also, please, wizards there, recommend me a good mocking framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do things like change constants or other class-wide data without trampling on the original class, dupping it looks to be the way to go -

```
class Lion
  ROAR = 'roar!'
end

L2 = Lion.dup

puts Lion::ROAR             # "roar!"
puts Lion::ROAR.object_id   # 2152285120

puts L2::ROAR               # "roar!"
puts L2::ROAR.object_id     # 2152285120

L2::ROAR = 'rawrrr'

puts Lion::ROAR             # "roar!"
puts Lion::ROAR.object_id   # 2152285120

puts L2::ROAR               # "rawrrr"
puts L2::ROAR.object_id     # 2152285000
```

Comment: Thanks for pondering this with me. I thought nobody would answer such a long question. I am quite sure what happens when I dup for instance an Array, but not sure what happens when I dup a class. You know, in my example, I subclass first (which allows me to leak methods using 'super') and then I dup. Do you think it would be better to dup first and then subclass?

Comment: It looks like either one would be fine, really. Have you seen differing results from doing one over the other?